# Kendo Grid - Parse and Format Date

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I get a date (the value parameter shown below) from SQL that looks like this: "2014-08-22T07:45:13.12Z". I want to format it so that I see this in the grid: "08/22/2014". I have tried this in the schema for the data source:

```
ModifiedDate: {
                  editable: false,
                  type: "date",
                  parse: function (value) {
                        var dt = kendo.parseDate(value, "yyyy/MM/dd");
                        return dt.getMonth() + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
                  }
               }
```

but get a null value for dt on the parseDate. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I did this instead to fix the problem.

```
        ModifiedDate: {
            editable: false,
            type: "date",
            parse: function (value) {
                var dt = new Date(value);
                return (dt.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + dt.getDate() + "/" + dt.getFullYear();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like below in your grid option:

```
{ field: "buyTime", title: "buyTime", format:"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", width: "120px" },
```